# Converting time stamp in informatica to date

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to display the time stamp in following format '2011-04-22 10:41:57.000' to date as '04/22/2011' but when it convert it to following form TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Date), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') it is displaying as null.

I am planning to use substring after the conversion

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: Is your source a table and target a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `TO_CHAR(Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')`

Comment: samik that too was giving error..So i used 'TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Date), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')' and later 'SUBSTR(Date_V,1,11)' and i got required output

Answer (score 0):

i used 'TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(Date), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')' and later 'SUBSTR(Date_V,1,11)' and i got required output